# Parametric equation of egg curves (transformed ellipses): $\frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{y^2}{b}t_i(x) = 1$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, parametric, elliptic-equations, implicit-function

I recently discovered ['egg' curves](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/eggcurves.htm), such as the following

$$\frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{y^2}{b}t_i(x) = 1$$

where $t_i$ could manifest as $t_1(x) = 1 + cx$ or $t_2(x) = e^{cx}$, with $c \geq 0$.

I was wondering if a parametric form exists, similar to the ordinary ellipse ($x = a\cos(t)$ and $y=\sin(t)$ for $t [0,2\pi]$), such that the shape can be plotted depending on the angle, rather than the range of x and y.

Example of my current approach (for $t_1(x)$):
$$bx^2 + ay^2(1 + cx) = ab \Rightarrow y^2(a + acx) = ab - bx^2 \Rightarrow y = \pm\sqrt{\frac{ab - bx^2}{a + acx}}$$

[Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u27L.png) showing then Egg curve based on the above equations, with $t_1 = 1 + 0.2$

Comment: Could you please give an explicit formula for $t_i(x)$? Try solving $$y=x\tan\theta, f(x,y)=1$$ for x and y in terms of $\theta$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Let's assume that $t_i(x) = 1 + cx$. Solving
$\frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{(x\tan\theta)^2}{b}(1 + cx) = 1$ results in solving for cubic roots.

Comment: See [_here_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4213352/solving-mathrmy-x-tan-theta-fx-y-0-implies-fx-x-tan-theta-0-on-t) for more information. This gets you an angle theta line and its intersection with $f(x,y)=1$ with $x(\theta),y(\theta)$ as the distance from the intersection to the $x$ or $y$ axis like the trig functions. I hope this works, tell me if not.